# No CORS support for traffic API calls?

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to integrate traffic API using javascript and have problem, because response does not contain CORS headers, I'm calling traffic API like this:

```
fetch('https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.3/incidents.json?bbox=38.74123075381228,-99.00329589843751;42.771211138625894,-94.010009765625&app_id=xx_appid&app_code=xx_appcode&c=US&lg=en&i18n=true&localtime=true&units=metric').then(x => console.log(x.json()));
```

If I call places API using following:

```
fetch('https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?at=52.5044,13.3909&q=restaurant&app_id=oyncTDRmj660ffCKFjBD&app_code=1b5UNr1Z1vHiseGGj9zZoA&pretty&callback=myCallbackFunction&Accept-Language=de').then(x => console.log(x))
```

it returns all headers just fine:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:63342
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Test, X-Map-Viewport, X-Mobility-Mode, X- 
Accept-Encoding, X-Date, Authorization, Accept, Date, Accept-Encoding, User-Agent, Geolocation, Origin, Content-Type, DNT, Cache-Control, Last-Modified, Expires, Pragma, X-NLP-TID
```

Any ideas if I'm doing something wrong or there's workaround (not counting jsonp)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding CORS authorization to headers in .htaccess file?

1. Allow CORS authorization to headers by adding within .htaccess file: 
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
2. Ensure your .htaccess file is located at root of your web-server.
3. Restart your web-server.

Comment: I far as I understand, problem lies in here.com servers, where I do not have access to. Adding .htaccess file to my server (localhost) won't help I guess.

Comment: Have you tried adding it to localhost, and reproduce same error?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the CORS error was returned for us by the service when the app_id and app_code were either invalid or not specified.  This was with the Javascript API rather than ReST but worth checking.